# What are drop targets in gedit's snippets?

Tags: code-snippets, gedit

There is a plugin for gedit to handle snippets. In the Snippets Manager under "Activation" for every snippet you can set the *drop targets*. There are some preformatted alternatives to choose between but you seem to able to compose your own alternatives too. The preformatted alternatives are: text, text/plain, text/xml, image, image/png, image/jpeg, audio and video.

What are drop targets? How do they work?

Below is a screenshot, the "Drop targets" field is visible under "Activation" in the lower right:

[image: gedit's Snippets Manager]